# If condition is not evaluated

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, if-statement

When running, it does not match the condition.
It skips it and runs the "else" block.

Could you help me?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText usern;
private EditText passw;
private Button logButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    usern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
    passw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    logButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(usern.getText().toString().equals("demo") && passw.getText().equals("demo")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem in detail.... what is expected behaviour what is actual behaviour etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with this line i guess.. You left out the toString() for passw

```
if(usern.getText().toString().equals("demo") && passw.getText().toString().equals("demo")){
                    ....
```

instead of

```
if(usern.getText().toString().equals("demo") && passw.getText().equals("demo")){
                    ....
```

Comment: Glad that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append toString() method for your password EditText.

```
passw.getText().toString().equals("demo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

if(usern.getText().toString().equals("demo") && passw.getText().equals("demo"))

Please check the password condition check. you have missed .toString() in it.

Use the code as below,

if(usern.getText().toString().equals("demo") && passw.getText().toString().equals("demo"))